# reading in a file in a loop and shell scripting

Tags: shell

```
if [ ${FILESTATUS} = "GOOD" ] ; then
    mv ${file} /export/home/goodFile
else
    mv ${file} /export/home/badFile
fi
```

want the above to be integrated to the below script. If both column pass the validation then THAT FILE(.csv) should be moved to the good file directory otherwise it should be moved bad file. Please help with integrating the logic/loop

```
for file in /export/home/*.csv ; do
awk -F', ' '
    # skip the header and blank lines
    NR == 1 || NF == 0 {next}

    # save the data
    { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) data[++nr,i] = $i }

    END {
        status = "OK"

        # verify column 1
        for (lineno=1; lineno <= nr; lineno++) {
            if (length(data[lineno,1]) == 0) {
                status = "BAD" 
                break
            }
        }
        printf "file: %s, verify column 1, status: %s\n", FILENAME, status

        #verify coulmn 2
        for(linenum = 1; linenum <nr; linenum++) {
        if (length(dataArr[linenum,2]) == 0){
        STATUS = "BAD"
        break
        }

        if ((dataArr[linenum,2]) !~ /^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)[0-9][0-9]$/){
        STATUS = "BAD"
        break
        }
    }

        # verify other columns ...
    }
' "$file"
done
```

Have this script that is supposed to read in about 10 or so .csv files from a directory. However I want this script to integrate the following where If the file is succesfully passed through validation steps it goes to the goodFile directory other wise goes to the badfile directory. I am not sure where to include this looping mechnaism.

Answer (score 0):

Anywhere in the awk code you write `STATUS = "BAD"`, replace that with `exit 1`

Then, in the for loop, test awk's exit status

```
for file in /export/home/*.csv ; do
    awk -F', ' '....' "$file"

    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        # "good" status
        mv ${file} /export/home/goodFile
    else
        # "bad" status
        mv ${file} /export/home/badFile
    fi
done
```

Comment: Hi also break is pretty much useless as well? STATUS = "BAD"
        break